# Why for loop changed my dataframe value to NaN returned from a function?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops

I have this function accepting two arguments and return a data frame with numbers in each row. Here is my simplified code:

```py
#df_sales is my dataframe which I already have loaded into jupyternote book

df_temp = pd.Dataframe()
def my_func(df, region):
    df_new = df.loc[df.regions == region]
    df_temp['sales'] = df_new['sales'] * 0.5
    df_temp['revenue'] = df_temp['sales'] * 12
    return df_temp

regions = ['north', 'south', 'west', 'east']
my_list = []
for region in regions:
   df_rev = my_func(df_sales, region)
   my_list.append(df_rev)
my_list
```

When I run `my_list`, it gives me 4 dataframes, all filled with `NaN`.

If I run the function `my_func` line by line, it returns a dataframe with number. This seems really too  strange. Can someone please enlighten me what's wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Please test the simplified code.

Comment: @Raymond Kwok. I am a new comer using stackoverflow. Thanks for editing my code in more readable format. i test it, nothing change. Looking forward to see solution. thanks!

Comment: Anyone sees something wrong with the logic within for loop ? seems cannot figure out what's wrong with all values filled with NaN

Comment: I didn't edit the code, but from your code `df.regions = region` should be wrong, and at least `df_sales` is not defined. Please run your simplified code and make sure it works through.

Comment: Sorry, my typo. df.regions = region should be (df.regions == region). df_sales is my dataframe which I have already loaded into my python code. the df_sales contains columns like regions, sales, etc.

Comment: I just don't get it.  one time my function returns a dataframe with numbers, if i rerun it with same argument, the function returns  a dataframe filled with all NaN

Comment: Can you update your question with a workable code that will produce the result in the way you describe?

Comment: I updated my code. i am not able to see anything wrong here. please point it out what's  the problem. this is really strange?!

Comment: when I run code line by line without in the loop.  it produces dataframe with number, however this is under condition that i have to run my_func(df, region) every time before i call it. really weird !!!

Comment: just to clarify when i say i have to run my_func(df, region). means function defination.

Comment: `df_sales` is not defined, not even with some sample data that can help me reproduce the problem that you describe. My last suggestion is to change `df.loc[df.regions == region]`. `df.loc[indices]` is for you to select rows based on `indices`, whereas `df.regions == region` gives you NOT indices but a list of booleans with which one right way to use it is `df[df.regions == region]`. If your problem doesn't get solved, I suggest you to prepare for code that's sufficient for anyone to run and see the problem that you see.

Comment: @Raymond Kwok.  I figured it out, the problem is that i defined  df_temp = pd.Dataframe() with function definition together. this should be a local variable. It wasted me so much time,  you are the only one responding my post. Thank you very much for your time and efforts. Appreciate it !!

Comment: I didn't catch that one. It's good to hear that you have.